# Connecting 2 Raspberry Pi's for Extra GPIO ports

Tags: gpio, connection

For the project I am working on, i will need more GPIO pins than the Raspberry 4B provides. I'm looking into combining 2 Raspberry 4B's together to get extra GPIO pins. I also looked into port expanders however my issue is that I'll need separate control for each pin. I'm wondering if there are any good resources to chaining 2 Pi's together as a master slave system with the slave Pi just for extra GPIO pins?

Comment: Use an MCP23017 GPIO chip. That gives you from 16 up to 128 extra GPIOs.

Comment: Would this allow me to have separate control of each port?

Comment: Yes it would allow that.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you can network the Pis you can use [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) or [gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to control all the GPIO from a single computer.

The computer can be one of the Pis or any other networked computer.

Each Pi needs to have the [pigpio daemon](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigpiod.html) running.